# Why is the viewport widget of QAbstractScrollArea not painted?

Tags: qt

The following code creates QAbstractScrollArea with a simple widget as a viewport. However, paintEvent is never called.

Why isn't Client::paintEvent called?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QAbstractScrollArea>

#include <iostream>

class Client : public QWidget {
        Q_OBJECT

public:
        Client(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) { }

        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override {
                std::cout << "GOT Client::paintEvent" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        QMainWindow         window(nullptr);
        QAbstractScrollArea scrollArea(&window);
        Client             *client(new Client(&scrollArea));

        client->resize(100,100);

        window.show();
        scrollArea.show();
        client->show();

        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
        scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);

        window.setCentralWidget(&scrollArea);
        scrollArea.setViewport(client);

        return app.exec();
}

#include "testcase.moc"
```

It can be built with:

```
moc testcase.cpp > testcase.moc
c++ -fPIC testcase.cpp -o testcase `pkg-config --cflags --libs Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets` -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

### Cause

The documentation of [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#details) says:

> QAbstractScrollArea is a low-level **abstraction** of a scrolling area.

Note: the empasis is mine

In other words, this class is not intended to be used directly, but to be subclassed. Otherwise you do not specify the actual behavior, hence, your widget is never shown, resp. the `paintEvent` is not called.

### Solution

In most cases using a [`QScrollArea`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) should do the job.

If you need some kind of custom behavior, you need to **subclass** `QAbstractScrollArea` and **reimplement** the corresponding methods according to your specific needs.

### Example

Here is an example of how to modify your code to use `QScrollArea`:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QScrollArea>
#include <iostream>

class Client : public QWidget {

    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Client(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    }

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
        std::cout << "GOT Client::paintEvent" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    auto *scrollArea = new QScrollArea(&window);
    auto *client = new Client(scrollArea);

    scrollArea->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
    scrollArea->setWidgetResizable(true);

    window.setCentralWidget(scrollArea);
    window.resize(300, 300);
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: This was just a demo of the problem. I need to manage the size of the viewport and scrollbars manually, this is why I need to use QAbstractScrollArea. QScrollArea shows a sub-area of a given viewport widget, and this isn't what I need.

Comment: @FlyingJay you might want to read the last edit I have made.

Comment: I need the widget to have a fixed size, same as of the visible area. QScrollArea automatically sets scrollbars state based on how much of the viewport is visible, and I need to calculate and set such positions myself. This is why I used QAbstractScrollArea. I don't think QScrollArea can support such use, because it manages scrollbars itself.

Comment: I'd just get rid of QAbstractScrollArea in favor of QWidget+QGridLayout+2xQScrollBar. QAbstractScrollArea doesn't do much in my situation, and I'd have a 100% control over what is going on.

Comment: @FlyingJay, you have asked _Why isn't Client::paintEvent called?_ and I have explained why. So, your question has been answered. It is a whole other story, if you were on the right path in the first place (the so called XY-problem). If you post a new question with enough details to identify your real problem, one might be able to propose a solution. However, the current question should be considered as answered.

Comment: QAbstractScrollArea's viewport widget has to also be painted. Just because it is a "low-level abstraction" doesn't mean that it shouldn't paint its viewport. Something is going on there, I just don't know what.

Comment: @FlyingJay, a brief look at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractscrollarea.cpp.html#_ZN19QAbstractScrollArea10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent) shows that QAbstractScrollArea paints nothing (the `paintEvent` has an empty implementation). From the comment: _This event handler can be __reimplemented__ in a subclass to receive paint events (passed in \a event), for the viewport() widget._ Note: the emphasis is mine. Once again, I insist that `QAbstractScrollArea` should be subclassed and its corresponding methods reimplemented, in order to do anything at all.

Comment: @FlyingJay, and __abstraction__ means exactly that - just an interface without implementation.